# How can I get the 3rd Friday of a month in Perl?

Tags: perl

I want to find the third Friday of any Month using Perl. I am using the code for the database but unable to find so, just getting the last friday

Comment: Can you include the code you're using?

Comment: I'd build a date object (whatever module) for the first of the month, find the day of the week for that date (which any module should be able to provide), and use modulo arithmetic to find the first Friday, and then add 14 days to find the third.

Answer (score 3):

Use the core module [Time::Piece](https://perldoc.pl/Time::Piece).

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };

use Time::Piece;
use Time::Seconds qw{ ONE_DAY ONE_WEEK };

my $year = 2022;
my $month = 8;

my $tp = 'Time::Piece'->strptime("$year-$month-1", '%Y-%m-%d');
$tp += ONE_DAY * ((5 - $tp->day_of_week) % 7);  # First Friday.
$tp += 2 * ONE_WEEK;
say $tp;
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same idea as ikegami. In code (using DateTime):

```
my $dt = DateTime->new(year => $year, month => $month, day => 1);
my $days_until_friday = (5 - $dt->day_of_week) % 7;
$dt->add(days => $days_until_friday + 14);
say $dt->ymd;
```

In fact, we know a bit more about dates (or a bit more about modular arithmetic, if you want to look at it that way): the third Friday of a month always occurs between the 15th and the 21st day of the month, inclusive (so does the third Monday, third Wednesday, etc. The 15th is the first "third whatever", and the 22nd is the first "fourth whatever".) And the 15th will fall on the same day of the week as the 1st.

So this is also valid:

```
my $dt = DateTime->new(year => $year, month => $month, day => 15);
$dt->add(days => (5 - $dt->day_of_week) % 7);
say $dt->ymd;
```

And, if you want to be really tricky (not recommended), this is also valid:

```
my $dt = DateTime->new(year => $year, month => $month, day => 17);
$dt->add(days => 5 - $dt->day_of_week); # No modulo!
say $dt->ymd;
```

I leave it to the interested reader to figure out why the last one works :)